# Implementing flowchart type workflows in java

Tags: java, workflow, amazon-web-services, flowchart, amazon-swf

We have a service that processes requests, it receives. Workflow for processing each request contains many steps, branches depending on some conditions(intermediate variable etc, result from some service call). Basically whole workflow can be written as a big **flowchart**.

Currently, my implementation contains lots of big `If-else` blocks. In each block, there are again many `if-else` sub blocks and so on. This code is very hard to manage and develop on. For instance if some new step/branches gets added in flow chart, Making corresponding code changes and testing those changes very painful.

Do there exist some libraries, that can be used in such situation? I have heard of `Amazon Simple Work Flow`, but can that be used here?

Answer (score 1):

I know that drools flow, http://www.jboss.org/drools/drools-flow allows modelling work-flows as flow graphs and it is Java based and has an eclipse plugin for graphical flow modelling.
Drools flow has been merged into jBPM5 http://www.jboss.org/jbpm/ which is a similar project.